# RcppArmadillo Package which Links to Header file from Another Package

Tags: c++, rcpp, r-package, rcpparmadillo

I'm trying to make an R package. It links to Rcpp, RcppArmadillo, and bayesm. Everything is working fine with the first two thanks to `Rcpp.package.skeleton()`.  When I try to use a function from bayesm called `rwishart`, however, I get an error. Before the error, the key file (mvp.cpp, in the src folder) is like this:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <bayesm.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
vec add_one(vec x) {
    return(x + 1);
}
```

Everything works. Notice that `#include <bayesm.h>` is in there, so I assume the header file can be located fine? The error comes when I add this:

```
List wishart_draw() {
   mat V = eye<mat>(3, 3);
   List W = rwishart(3, V);
   return(W); 
}
```

The error message is: `symbol not found in flat namespace (__Z8rwishartdRKN4arma3MatIdEE)`

I hope that is detailed enough. I will happily provide more information.

Comment: Some C++ libraries can be accessed header-only. But most libraries and packages also require linking -- and that is what the linker tells you here.  One can arrange for a package to make its functions callable by other functions but it is a little involved and you would need cooperation from Peter Rossi on this.  So in short maybe your best bet is just to copy the function source (with attribution).

Comment: Armadillo has its own functions related to Wishart distributions. See the [`wishrnd()`](https://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#wishrnd) and [`iwishrnd()`](https://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#iwishrnd) functions.  This can be easier than using another package.